# Install microsoft/vcpkg on jetson nano

Tags: c++, vcpkg, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to install [microsoft/vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) on jetson nano (Ubuntu 18.04).

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
```

Clones everything correctly, then

```
./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
```

The error I get

```
Unable to determine a binary release of vcpkg; attempting to build from source.
Downloading vcpkg tool sources
Building vcpkg-tool...
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting the C++ compiler in use
-- Detecting the C++ compiler in use - gcc
-- Module support is disabled.
-- Version: 9.1.0
-- Build type: Release
-- CXX_STANDARD: 17
-- Performing Test has_std_17_flag
-- Performing Test has_std_17_flag - Success
-- Performing Test has_std_1z_flag
-- Performing Test has_std_1z_flag - Success
-- Required features: cxx_variadic_templates
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Performing Test CPP_ATOMIC_BUILTIN
-- Performing Test CPP_ATOMIC_BUILTIN - Success
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/build
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[42/191] Building CXX object CMakeFile...glib.dir/src/vcpkg/binarycaching.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/binarycaching.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++ -DVCPKG_BASE_VERSION=2999-12-31 -DVCPKG_VERSION=unknownhash -I/mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/include -I_deps/fmt-src/include -I_cmrc/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -include /mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/include/pch.h -pthread -std=c++1z -MD -MT CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/binarycaching.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/binarycaching.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/binarycaching.cpp.o -c /mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/src/vcpkg/binarycaching.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62,
                 from /mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/include/pch.h:25,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider, std::default_delete<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> >&}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:331:31:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> >]’
/mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:42:57:   required from ‘vcpkg::ExpectedHolder<T>::ExpectedHolder(Fwd&&) [with Fwd = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> >&; typename std::enable_if<(! is_same_v<vcpkg::ExpectedHolder<T>, typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<_SrcTuple>::type>::type>), int>::type <anonymous> = 0; T = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> >]’
/mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:77:85:   required from ‘vcpkg::ExpectedT<T, Error>::ExpectedT(ConvToT&&) [with ConvToT = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> >&; typename std::enable_if<(is_convertible_v<ConvToT, T> && (! is_same_v<typename std::remove_reference<_SrcTuple>::type, Error>)), int>::type <anonymous> = 0; T = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider> >; Error = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/src/vcpkg/binarycaching.cpp:2312:12:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = vcpkg::IBinaryProvider; _Dp = std::default_delete<vcpkg::IBinaryProvider>]’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from /mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/src/vcpkg-tool-2022-12-14/include/pch.h:35,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:383:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
[47/191] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/build.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

ninja version I have installed 1.8.2

I have tried to reinstall ninja and tried to use --useSystemBinaries flag recommended [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/10955#issuecomment-617886569)

```
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh --useSystemBinaries
```

but it said

```
Warning: -useSystemBinaries no longer has any effect; ignored. Note that the VCPKG_USE_SYSTEM_BINARIES environment variable behavior is not changed.
```

then continued the above process.

Please help to solve this problem.

If you need an additional information, just tell me.

Comment: File an issue with the vcpkg project instead.

Comment: Not a solution, but the specific error is in an attempt to copy a unique_ptr. That doesn't work by design, as a copy wouldn't be unique anymore. No idea why this happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile an earlier version of vcpkg.

```
git checkout 2022.01.31
```

Or you can upgrade jetpack to 5.