# CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja"

Tags: ninja, vcpkg, nvidia-jetson-nano

I try to install [microsoft/vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) on Jetson Nano (Ubuntu 18.04)

I do

```
$ git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
```

then

```
./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
```

And I get

```
Unable to determine a binary release of vcpkg; attempting to build from source.
Building vcpkg-tool...
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/ALPR_Cpp/vcpkg/buildtrees/_vcpkg/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Then of course I installed ninja-build version 1.8.2 but another problem occurred there ([see the problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74861292/install-microsoft-vcpkg-on-jetson-nano?noredirect=1#comment132114078_74861292)). Is there any other solution without using Ninja?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have `/usr/bin/ninja` and am using `CMakePresets.json` with field, `"generator": "Ninja"`. 
If I `cmake .. --preset=debug` (using presets from `CMakePresets.json`), it throws that error.
However, I have no problem with `cmake .. -GNinja`.
Perhaps a `vcpkg` bug...?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install ninja-build
```

Comment: Downvoted because he specified in his question: "Then of course I installed ninja-build version"